# Moving Native Window in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, air

How to move native window when any display object start drag in `Flash` action script? As we do with clock gadget in windows 7.

Actually, I am trying to make my custom clock that will work like a clock in windows 7.

Comment: Your question needs more explanation? Are you targeting `FlashPlayer` or `Air`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are targeting Air, then use `stage.nativeWindow.startMove();` like so:

```
private function dragWindow(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    stage.nativeWindow.startMove();
}

clock.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragWindow);
```